# Best way to Connect node.js and server engine Net.Core

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, json, zeromq

I would like to find the best way to connect javascript to a c# engine.

In my case I have a c# process that manages the raspberry GPIOs and I want to expose a set of functions to multiple js clients which can also be remote.

I tried to implement an MQ service with serialization commands in JSON but the structure to expose all the commands and manage the response of the functions is very elaborate.

my engine exposes workbench with a list of example functions:

```
    public interface IWorkbench
    {
        public void SetDigitalOutput(byte[] output);

        public byte[] GetDigitalInput();

        public double GetTemperatureBySensor();
    }
```

I need to be able from a js client to call this set of functions and get the result.
What can I use to make my life easy?

Comment: Simple HTTP requests? Websockets?

Comment: a ready and robust library that serialized and exposes functions? Websockets is fine too.
I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Which library is best to use to create a WebSocket server that automatically handles connections and other events?

Comment: "best" is a subjective term and we don't really do recommendations here, but if you're talking about .NET/C# then SignalR is the obvious choice.